# APPLESCRIPT: Keycodes double tab and enter not working

Tags: applescript, applescript-numbers

hi I have this code to open up a program and find a documentnumber.

When I physically type the keys on my keyboard it works.

I just need to fix the following code, instead off typing, through code creating the keycodes :

tab
 tab
 enter

So I made this:

```
tell application "System Events"
    key code 48
    key code 48
    key code 76
end tell
```

This should work right?

Answer (score 0):

It *should* work, but it doesn't seem to. Not sure why that is...

Try this instead:

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke tab & tab & return
end tell
```

Comment: It should work indeed but it doesn't, I think it comes because of the software program. It's a kind of server-file organizer. We work with multiple colleagues on the same license. Sometimes the program does strange things. I think because we work with multiple users in 1 account.